# Pandas dataframe rolling covariance calculation with min_periods applicable to only one column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to compute the covariance of columns `A` and `B` in the below dataframe in such a way that covariance should only be calculated if there is at least 3 values in the rolling window in column `B`. In other words: we create rolling windows of size 5 and if there are at least 3 values in column `B`, we calculate the covariance of the two series. Else, the output is `NaN`. Column `cov` shows the intended output:

```
    A   B   cov
0       1   nan
1       3   nan
2       2   nan
3       3   nan
4   1   1   nan
5   2   2   0.5
6   3       0.5
7   4   4   2.33
8   3       2.33
9   4   5   1.67
10  2       nan
11  3   1   1.17
12  4   2   0.83
13  2   1   1.25
14  2   3   -0.08
```

My idea was
`df['A'].rolling(5).cov(df['B'].rolling(5,min_periods=3))`

However, this gave me an output series full of `NaN`s. Then I added `min_periods=1` to the first `rolling()` like so:

`df['A'].rolling(5,min_periods=1).cov(df['B'].rolling(5,min_periods=3))`

This gave me the following output:

```
0     nan
1     nan
2     nan
3     nan
4     nan
5     0.50
6     0.50
7     2.33
8     2.33
9     1.67
10    0.00
11    1.17
12    0.83
13    1.25
14   -0.08
```

This is almost correct. However, row `10` should be a `NaN` instead of `0.00`, since the rolling window in column `B` doesn't have minimum 3 valid values, hence no output should be computed. Where am I mistaken with my current approach?